# Why do the response time differ dramatically between two different ways of taking arguments to httping command?

Tags: ping

I've installed `httping` command on my OS X Mavericks through homebrew, and tried to use it to connect to apple's web site in two different ways, but got dramatically different performances.

When I tried to connect to it using `httping apple.com`, the response time was about 240 ms. However, when I connected by writing `httping http://www.apple.com`, the time was reduced to about 16 ms, which is more than 10 times faster if I understand it correctly.

Moreover, it looks like the former send 147 bytes while the latter 228 bytes.

So where does the result originate? And which one should I use to correctly measure the response time?

Note that `ping http://www.apple.com` doesn't work at all - it's the reason I installed `httping` to begin with.

Thanks.

Comment: `So where does the result originate? And which one should I use to correctly measure the response time?` - Why do you think you need to measure the response time to Apple?   What are you actually trying to learn?  Why do you think connecting to Apple is the best test?  Apple like any huge web site is going to be distributed across a large number of systems and locations.  Trying to measure the response time is meaningless.

Comment: It doesn't have any meanings to use Apple's site - it's just that I picked it up to learn about how to use `httping` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the two names `apple.com` and `www.apple.com` resolve to completely different addresses.  One appears to be a CDN.  Since you are connecting to different systems, it is not at all surprising that you are getting completely different results.

```
root@server:/etc/nagios3# host apple.com
apple.com has address 17.149.160.49
apple.com has address 17.178.96.59
apple.com has address 17.172.224.47

root@server:/etc/nagios3# host www.apple.com
www.apple.com is an alias for www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net.
www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net is an alias for www.apple.com.edgekey.net.
www.apple.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e3191.dscc.akamaiedge.net.
e3191.dscc.akamaiedge.net has address 2.19.141.15
e3191.dscc.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2600:1409:a:1a4::c77
e3191.dscc.akamaiedge.net has IPv6 address 2600:1409:a:1a3::c77
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion of the use of Apple's. Then which one should I use when I develop my own web service?

Comment: Which one what?  That question doesn't really make sense without context.

Comment: @user2360798 When you develop your own web service, you should use the name of the web service.